# Overfitting and linear methods

Tags: machine-learning

Overfitting happens for some methods in certain conditions, but there is generic rule for all linear classifiers to overfitting?
I know that regularization is a remedy for overfitting, but I am asking the behavior of methods before regularization.

Comment: We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking.  Typing "linear overfit" into Google immediately gives me answers to your question (e.g., http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics-2/the-danger-of-overfitting-regression-models is the second result).  Typing "linear overfit" into [the Stackexchange search bar](http://stackexchange.com) turns up many more: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/175771/2921, http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/35276/2921, http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/71946/2921.  In the future I encourage you to do more research before asking.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I already searched for it, but I am looking for short conditions. I mean I don't know if there generic answer for all linear methods together, or everyone has its conditions separately.

Comment: If you've already searched and found material that didn't meet your needs, please tell us that in your question.  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.  Also, it's usually better to ask only one question per post.  I encourage you to click the 'edit' link to edit your question and clarify what you are asking, what research you've done, and what you've already found.  I don't know what "short conditions" means.